# How to convert this STRING into time + date

Tags: r, string, datetime

I have a df below:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
date<-c("2018-05-14","2018-05-15","2018-05-16","2018-05-17")
time<-c("012230.627 GMT","070026.886 GMT","070036.941 GMT","173917.192 GMT")
df<-data.frame(id,date,time)
```

Expected output would be

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
date<-c("2018-05-14","2018-05-15","2018-05-16","2018-05-17")
time<-c("012230.627 GMT","070026.886 GMT","070036.941 GMT","173917.192 GMT")
DateTime<-c("2018-05-14 1:22:30 AM","2018-05-15 7:00:26 AM","2018-05-16 7:00:36 AM","2018-05-17 5:39:17 PM")
```

I wonder how I can convert it to date+time so that I can perform arithmetic calculations on it.

Comment: `strptime(paste(date, time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S", tz = "GMT")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked out for me, as time is a string I'm taking the first 6 characters and then format the date with `strptime`

```
date<-c("2018-05-14","2018-05-15","2018-05-16","2018-05-17")
time<-c("012230.627 GMT","070026.886 GMT","070036.941 GMT","173917.192 GMT")
time <- substr(time,1,6)

date_time <- paste(date, time)
strptime(date_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S", tz="GMT")
>>>
[1] "2018-05-14 01:22:30 GMT" "2018-05-15 07:00:26 GMT"
[3] "2018-05-16 07:00:36 GMT" "2018-05-17 17:39:17 GMT"
```

Comment: sorry @dww, by the time I started typing, there wasn't yet a comment

Comment: Wish there was a way to accept both the answers, thank you both!